# How do I make ObjectMapper ignore empty string fields during deserialization?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I have this service method for my edit API that maps my pojo class to an entity class for update operation. The CustomerDetail is my Dto class.

```
public CustomerRegistration editCustomerDetails
(Long id, CustomerDetail customerDetail) throws JsonMappingException 

{

        CustomerRegistration customer = customerRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId(id);
        if (customer == null)
            return null;

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.updateValue(customer, customerDetail);
        customer.setModifiedTs(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
        customerRegistrationRepository.save(customer);
        return customer;

    }
```

Let's say I want to update the customer details of customerID 1, my request body consists of these fields:

```
{
"firstName":"Leon",
"middleName":"",
"lastName":"Kennedy",
"addr1":"cross",
"addr2":"new"
}
```

My customer table already has a middle name for customerID 1. I want to ignore the update operation for middleName field in the table as the request body has an empty string. In my case it is being set to null/empty in the table. How can I avoid this?

My pojo class has already been annotated with @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)

Comment: What if your json will not include middleName?

Comment: @balderman Then it will not be updated in the table.

Comment: You have to rethink your client/server contract. What if the client wants to reset the middle name? If you treat an absent attribute, an empty or null string all the same there is no chance to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing annotation value from

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) // ignores null values
```

To :

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) // ignores empty values (empty string, null, etc)
```

Comment: I added this as a class level annotation in my pojo class. But it does not seem to work for some reason. The table is getting updated with empty values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you try to achieve very specific logic by means of general purpose method.

**objectMapper.updateValue** executes very simple logic: converting source object to the type of target object and then merging result into target object.

In your case you want to apply specific logic (skip updating a field of target object in case it's empty in the source object). This logic is not assumed by this method. There's even no parameter in this method that could switch on/off this logic.

You may use **objectMapper.readValue** to parse input string into target object, but then apply the merge logic you want manually.